# AWS - S3 - Creating a Bucket Policy - Error: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Trying to create an Amazon Web Services - S3 bucket policy, but when running the script I get the following error. Where exactly is my access being denied? Could this issue relate to how I set up my aws configur

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\githubb\aws\s3operations.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(create_bucket_policy())
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\githubb\aws\s3operations.py", line 36, in create_bucket_policy
    Policy=policy_string
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occur

red (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Access Denied
```

The following is my script:

```
import boto3
import json

BUCKET_NAME ='patricksbucket'

def s3_client():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    """:type : pyboto3.s3"""
    return s3

def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    return s3_client().create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={
            'LocationConstraint': 'us-east-2'
            }
        )

def create_bucket_policy():
    bucket_policy = {
        "Vesrion": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement":[
            {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action":["s3:*"],
            "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::patricksbucket/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
    policy_string = json.dumps(bucket_policy)

    return s3_client().put_bucket_policy(
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Policy=policy_string
    )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #print(create_bucket(BUCKET_NAME))
    print(create_bucket_policy())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could happens because of several reasons although mainly related to your credentials or your policy. Anyway, you just follow the permission specifications that say how to grant *everything* with a wildcard as I see in your code

An example from [Amazon Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html) can shed a light

```
    "Action": "*"
    "Action": "s3:*"
```

The other reason, additional to the one above, is your credentials. For example, if you use [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

```
    $ aws configure
    AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
    AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
    Default region name [None]: us-west-2
    Default output format [None]: json
```

Hope it helps (:

Answer (score 1):

Setting the permissions in S3 can be a bit tricky. I have the same problem sometimes that i take a lot of time to get it working. But in Most times you have to set the correct policy and rights. First of all you have a typo in your policy:

```
 "Vesrion": "2012-10-17",
 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Perhaps the policy is not applied. You should check that in the S3 Backend. There you can change and test some things and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have SCP blocking "s3:putBucketAcl, s3:putBucketPulicAccess" from organization. during creating s3 bucket, those actions are denied endup denying createBucket. After allow those permissions, the s3 bucket was created successfully.